# What would a person *unmoving* look like on a Minkowski diagram?

Tags: black-holes, relativity, special-relativity

1. If you were to draw a person on a Minkowski diagram, that was unmoving (though time was still passing) what would that look like? 
   (As a light cone and ignore the observer.)
   [image: Minkowski diagram]
2. Also what would it look like if you drew a person looking into a black hole (at a safe distance) but NOT accelerating away? (also as a light cone)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "as a light cone". An point-object's path through space-time is represented not by a cone, but a curve.

I can probably help you on your first question. First, *pick* a position for your person at time zero. Plot this point on your space-time diagram. Then, choose a (short) time later. Plot the position for your person. (Did the position change?) Keep doing this. Connect the dots.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is standing still his world line is vertical in minkowski diagram. It doesnen't matter if he is observing a black hole or an apple...

**EDIT 1:**

After taking a closer look at your image I saw that the cone you drew is colored yellow. For the sake of simplicity lets consider a 1D example (we have spatial dimension "$x$" and time timension $ct$) where the *"light cone"* becomes a *"light X"*. *"Light X"* consists of two asymptotes angled $45^\circ$ and angled $135^\circ$ according to the spatial direction $x$. It is important to realize that:

> only the objects which travel with the speed of light can exist on the
>   asymptotes of *"light X"* and that theese objects can only moove in the
>   direction of asymptotes mentioned above or paralell to them.

Now tell me if you need an extra explaination on how the *"light X"* is derived and why asymptotes are angled at $35^\circ$ and $135^\circ$.